# Asymptotic growth of translation in random walk.

Tags: asymptotics, random-walk

Let's consider a random walk with translation $$F(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}X(n)$$
Where $X(n)$ is a random variable distribiuted independently and equal to $0$ or $1$.

What is asymptotic growth of $F(N)$?

i.e.

I am looking for function $f$ which satisfy:$$F(N)=O(f(N))$$
Is this true that $f(N)=N^{0.5}$

I hope that someone will help me.

Comment: To be clear, $X$ has a probability of $1/2$ being $0$ and $1/2$ being $1$, correct? It's not really clear from your wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that $\mu_X=\frac 1 2$ and $\sigma_X=\frac 1 2(0-\frac 1 2)^2+\frac 1 2(1-\frac 1 2)^2=\frac 1 4$.

Let's consider:

$$G(N)=\frac{F(N)}{N}=\frac 1 N \sum_{n=1}^N X(n)$$

By the Central Limit Theorem, as $N\rightarrow \infty $, $G$ becomes normally distributed with $\mu_G=\mu_X=\frac 1 2$ and $\sigma_G=\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt N}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt N}$

Now, $F=NG$. Therefore, as $N\rightarrow \infty$, $F$ becomes normally distributed with $\mu_F=N\mu_G=\frac N 2$ and $\sigma_F=N\sigma_G=\frac{\sqrt N}{4}$. Therefore, the expected value of $F$ is $O(N)$ and the standard deviation of $F$ is $O(\sqrt N)$.

In short, in the average-case scenario, $F$ is $O(N)$. Also, in the worst-case scenario, $F=N$, so $F$ is $O(N)$ in worst-case scenario as well.

Comment: But how the expected value determines "big O" notation?

Comment: @mkultra Well, really the worst-case scenario determines big O notation, but sometimes, you will see people talk about average-case complexity as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity